# Connect to SQL Server Developer edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I recently installed Microsoft SQL Server Express for a project of mine, and I was able to connect to the instance with SQL Server Management Studio and everything worked fine. Then I realized that I needed the Developer edition for importing data the way I wanted, so I attempted to remove the Express edition and I installed Developer edition from Microsoft's website.

I tried to connect to the developer instance in SSMS first with `[computer name]\MSSQLSERVER` (`[computer name]\SQLEXPRESS` worked before) but that didn't work. I then tried many other things, including updating and reinstalling SSMS and the developer instance, and repairing the instance with the installation center.

When I look under the local server groups on SSMS I see the default one that's just my computer's name, and I see `[computer name]\sqlexpress`, but I don't see the one with the instance name of the developer edition (which should be `[computer name]\mssqlserver`, right?). Connecting the the express edition doesn't work anymore either, I think as a result of my attempts to uninstall it. Connecting to the default works, but it isn't Developer (which I know from trying to import data).

When I look at the Server Configuration Manager, though, it shows "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" as a service which is running, but SSMS refuses to recognize it.

I'm a total beginner at this, so there's a good chance I'm missing something very obvious. I'm also unsure about the "connect now" button on the window that says "installation has completed successfully" which to takes you to the command line window, and whether that has anything to do with this. I don't really remember doing anything with it back when I installed express.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The instance that's shown as `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` in SQL Server Configuration Manager is the **default** instance to which you connect *without* specifying an instance name, just using one of these:

```
.
(local)
your-machine-name
```

as the server/instance name.

Comment: I have tried that, but then when I try to import data from a flat file source, a warning shows up on the "Run Package" page of the Import and Export Wizard which states "In SQL Server Express, Web, or Workgroup, you can run the package that the Import and Export Wizard creates, but cannot save it. To save packages that the wizard creates, you must upgrade to SQL Server Standard, Enterprise, Developer or Evaluation." This suggests that I'm not using a developer instance.

Comment: @fisherman45: if you run `SELECT @@VERSION` - what is the output? Is it a Developer edition or not?

Comment: Pretty much everything I see (including that) suggests that it is developer edition.

Comment: I looked into it further, and I installed Integration Services, which fixed my problem. I was just misled by the error message they gave me. Thanks for your help @marc_s.